# How do I test a gem that modifies ActiveRecord with different DB's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord, rubygems

I have created [a gem](http://github.com/splendeo/activerecord-reset-pk-sequence) that adds a new method to the class ActiveRecord::Base. I have tested the gem manually (creating a rails application) and it works, but I would like to  create an automatic test battery to test it properly. Is there any gem I can use as reference?

Thanks!!

Sergio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Travis config for Rails, it seems to run it several times against each DB:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/ci/travis.rb

Crude but effective :)